# Which should i use for scraping data from website Google appEngine, computeEngine or cloudFunctions

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-functions, cheerio

I want to build a nodejs application to scrape data from a website every 20mins and store it in firebase. Can you please tell me which product of google( compute engine, app engine or cloud functions ) is effective for this requirement as below are the things i am expecting to do,
1. Run Nodejs, cheerio to scrape data from website and store in firebase
2. Schedule it to run 20mins initially later may change it to 30mins or 1hr.

After reading the docs, i know that there are too many ways to implement this, but i am looking for a cost/resource effective way.

Pointers and ideas would be good.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Each of these products *can* be used to implement the functionality you want. What's best for me is not necessarily best for you, so there no objective way to answer correctly, which is precisely why such questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow. I recommend picking one, and trying to implement your use-case.

Comment: Will do thanks Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Host the Node.js application within the App Engine[[1]](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/) as Cloud Functions are event-driven[[2]](https://cloud.google.com/functions/). You can use App Engine standard[[3]](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/) or App Engine flexible[[4]](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/) environment. For the scheduling part, Google Cloud Platform has a Cron Service[[5]](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/reliable-task-scheduling-compute-engine) and you can create a cron job for your task hitting App Engine[[6]](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml). You can find a sample design here[[7]](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/reliable-task-scheduling-compute-engine-sample).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much time your script spends waiting on requests. During that time the script is idle but you're getting charged at a super-high rate.
If you're doing a lot of concurrency then I would say do it with cloud functions.
Another pro of doing it that way is your ip won't get blocked because it will be different every time.
Regarding scheduling, I'm not sure if Google lets do that, but I know AWS does.

Comment: Pguardiario. When you say "Another pro of doing it that way is your ip won't get blocked because it will be different every time." When you do it via functions you don't get blocked, is it ?

Comment: No, I meant the functions will use a different ip address every time whereas app engine will use the same one every time. So it's harder to block the function.

Answer (score 0):

A cost effective/simple way would be to use cronjob.org and have it send an http request to your cloud functions url to trigger it. If you're worried about other people triggering it, tell your cronjob to send an http header w/ an api key.  Check this api key in your cloud function code to verify cronjob.org sent the request. I don't think it gets any more easy/cheap than this.